# Can't translate wxWidgets program

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm trying to implement the wxLocale translation system into my program.
i've already implemented the wxLocale translation load (based on the 'Internat' example from the wxWidgets samples.

the translation files are loaded, but strings aren't translated.
a member of the wxWidgets forums built the program and the translations are loaded!, so i guess that something is wrong with my compiler, libs or macros.

maybe someone here will be able to help me...

[program built by doublemax from wxwidgets forum](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/mklqhne1o8o72/wxWidgets_translation)

[the program source code](https://github.com/israpps/HDL-Batch-installer/tree/internat)

[wxwidgets settings](https://github.com/israpps/HDL-Batch-installer/blob/internat/HDL-Batch-installer/wxwidgets/build.cfg)

i'm compiling the program trough Code::Blocks & MingW from Code::Blocks

Comment: did you try to build multi-lib version of the library and use it in the new C::B project. MONOLITHIC should be used in C::B developments itself and it is rarely tested by wx core devs. If it will behave the same - try with 3/1/5. Also see what is different between the `internat` sample and your code. Also, check where are you putting the translation files. And finally - I'm sure DM did use the multi-lib setup...

Comment: multi-lib didn't work

Comment: did you try my other suggestions? Namely see what's the difference between the sample and your own code? Also - what locale do you have installed on the system and what language translation you are trying to test?

Comment: as i said, doublemax compiled the program and it worked for him